# Lock WPF Datagrid HorizontalScrollBar to bottom of window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid on the last row of a Grid. When the DataGrid has a lot of rows, the height expands past the bottom of my UserControl. I'm trying to align the bottom of the DataGrid (or the Grid) with the bottom of my UserControl and have it remain aligned if I adjust the window size. The VerticalScrollBar remains aligned with the right side of the UserControl perfectly fine, but the HorizontalScrollBar doesn't.

I've tried replacing the container from a Grid to a DockPanel and a StackPanel with no luck. I've tried dozens of different configurations at this point, none of them worked.

```xml
<reactiveui:ReactiveUserControl 
    x:Class="MyNamespace.Views.MyView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Views"
    xmlns:reactiveui="http://reactiveui.net"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.ViewModels"
    xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Models"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    x:TypeArguments="viewmodels:MyViewModel"
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <Grid Margin="16 16 0 0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Name="ExcelData" 
                  EnableColumnVirtualization="True" 
                  EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
                  Grid.Row="2" 
                  AutoGeneratedColumns="ExcelData_AutoGeneratedColumns">
            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridCell}">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="16"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</reactiveui:ReactiveUserControl>
```

Code-behind:

```cs
public partial class MyView : ReactiveUserControl<MyViewModel>
{
    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new MyViewModel();

        this.WhenActivated(disposableRegistration =>
        {
            // populate data grid
            this.OneWayBind(ViewModel,
                viewModel => viewModel.DataActive,
                view => view.ExcelData.ItemsSource)
                .DisposeWith(disposableRegistration);
        });
    }

    private void ExcelData_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var column in ExcelData.Columns)
        {
            // set auto generated column headers to empty string
            if (column.Header.ToString().Contains("Column"))
            {
                column.Header = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The DataGrid height grows to the number of rows I have unless I lock the height to a specific value with Height="".

Here's what it looks like on the bottom:

[image]

once the window height is resized to be greater than the height of the DataGrid, the HorizontalScrollBar seems to properly attach itself to the bottom:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```xml
<Grid Margin="16 16 0 0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid Name="ExcelData" 
              EnableColumnVirtualization="True" 
              EnableRowVirtualization="True"
              Grid.Row="2" 
              AutoGeneratedColumns="ExcelData_AutoGeneratedColumns">
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridCell}">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="16"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

I deleted the `ScrollViewer` and `FrozenColumnCount` property from `DataGrid`.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it didn't work. I've updated my post with more code, particularly to include that I am using a ReactiveUserControl from ReactiveUI. I also updated the XML to what I'm currently trying that isn't working.